# How can i get the timediff of two different rows in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently monitoring for overtime. I want to display if that employee has exceeded his/her time on work.

[image]

Comment: How do you tell if an employee *exceeded his/her time on work*? i.e. What is the maximum work time? Is it 8 hours? It would also be helpful if you show us the solutions you have tried. Welcome to SO btw

Comment: a. don't use images of data, give us sample data we can reuse, b.include the table name and column names otherwise we make-up stuff for those

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is, store the In and Out values as timestamps so you can easily subtract integers and get the diff.

Answer (score 0):

Appears you will need to use a GROUP BY clause with MIN() and MAX() functions, both of which will need case expressions to determine In or Out dates.

```
SELECT
      empid
    , MIN(CASE WHEN `type` = 'In' THEN `date` END)
    , MAX(CASE WHEN `type` = 'Out' THEN `date` END)
    , SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(CASE WHEN `type` = 'In' THEN `date` END),MAX(CASE WHEN `type` = 'Out' THEN `date` END)))
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY
      empid
```

**IF** those "date" columns are timestamps, then using TIMESTAMPDIFF() will work and by using seconds as units passed into SEC_TO_TIME you get an output in hh:mm:ii format

for a "per day" result see this: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f435e/13)

```
create table logs (Pin varchar(20),
                   Mode varchar(100),
                   Date_time datetime);

insert into logs values ('16514','IN','2015-06-12 16:37:46');
insert into logs values ('16514','OUT','2015-06-13 06:37:46');
insert into logs values ('16514','IN','2015-06-13 16:37:46');
insert into logs values ('16514','OUT','2015-06-14 06:37:46');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
       pin
     , in_datetime
     , out_datetime
     , date_format(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,in_datetime,out_datetime)),'%H:%i:%S') as duration
from (
      select
            pin
          , date_time as in_datetime
          , (select l.date_time from logs as l
             where l.date_time > logs.date_time
             and l.mode = 'OUT'
             order by l.date_time ASC
             LIMIT 1) as out_datetime
      from logs
      where mode = 'IN'
    ) as relog
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f435e/13/0)**:

```
|   pin |            in_datetime |           out_datetime | duration |
|-------|------------------------|------------------------|----------|
| 16514 | June, 12 2015 16:37:46 | June, 13 2015 06:37:46 | 14:00:00 |
| 16514 | June, 13 2015 16:37:46 | June, 14 2015 06:37:46 | 14:00:00 |
```

Comment: hello, your solution works for me fine. but how can i check the duration of their working time per day?

Comment: the 4th column (SEC_TO_TIME) is the duration. Just group by DAY as well as by empID

Comment: hello, when i tried adding the date on the GROUP BY it returns NULL value

Comment: As i have zero data of yours., and zero access to your db, what you propose i do? Relook at my answer that is as much as i can do. Setup a sqlfiddle and give me the url to that maybe